# Constructing the hashed token signature for cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create hashed token for creating a document in cosmos db but I am always getting 405 method not allowed, can someone verify whether the below format I provided is correct or not?

```
url = https://cosmos-test-cache.documents.azure.com/dbs/FamilyDB/colls/FamilyCollection/docs/123456
ResourceLink = /dbs/FamilyDB/colls/FamilyCollection/docs/123456
ResourceType = docs
HTTP verb = POST

Response

{
  "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
  "message": "RequestHandler.Post"
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to create document using cosmos db rest api?

Comment: @JayGong yes I want to create a Json document with key 123456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you observe the official [cosmos db rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-document),you could find that url sample of Creating Document is `https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}/docs`

[image]

However,your url is

`https://cosmos-test-cache.documents.azure.com/dbs/FamilyDB/colls/FamilyCollection/docs/123456` which is for [Get Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/get-a-document),not Create Document. So,it is identified as a `Get` request rather than a `POST` request.

Then the error `405 "MethodNotAllowed"` occurs.

---

Updates:

Let me fix it.

If you use sdk, you could set the disableAutomaticIdGeneration property to avoid setting the id.It will generate id automatically for you.

Like:

[image]

But according to the [rest api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-document),the id property is Required. The ID field is automatically added when a document is created without specifying the ID value.

[image]

---

Please refer to sample java rest code:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class CreateDocumentRest {

    private static final String account = "***";
    private static final String key = "***";


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String urlString = "https://" + account + ".documents.azure.com/dbs/db/colls/coll/docs";

        //prepare for the json body
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("name", "A");
        jsonObject.put("id", "123");

        String jsonStr = jsonObject.toString();
        String encoding = "UTF-8";
        System.out.println(jsonStr);
        byte[] data = jsonStr.getBytes(encoding);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(urlString)).openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        getFileRequest(conn, data);
        OutputStream outStream = conn.getOutputStream();

        outStream.write(data);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());


        BufferedReader br = null;
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getErrorStream())));
        } else {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
        }
        System.out.println("Response body : " + br.readLine());
    }

    public static void getFileRequest(HttpURLConnection request, byte[] data)
            throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String date = fmt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + " GMT";
        String stringToSign = "POST".toLowerCase() + "\n"
                + "docs".toLowerCase() + "\n"
                + "dbs/db/colls/coll" + "\n"
                + date.toLowerCase() + "\n"
                + "" + "\n";
        System.out.println("stringToSign : " + stringToSign);
        String auth = getAuthenticationString(stringToSign);

        request.setRequestMethod("POST");
        request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-date", date);
        request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2017-02-22");
        request.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);
        request.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(data.length));
        request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    }

    private static String getAuthenticationString(String stringToSign) throws Exception {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(key), "HmacSHA256"));
        String authKey = Base64.encode(mac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        System.out.println("authkey:" + authKey);
        String auth = "type=master&ver=1.0&sig=" + authKey;
        auth = URLEncoder.encode(auth);
        System.out.println("authString:" + auth);
        return auth;
    }

}
```

Per my observation,please adjust your `ResourceLink` as `dbs/FamilyDB/colls/FamilyCollection` and `url` as `https://cosmos-test-cache.documents.azure.com/dbs/FamilyDB/colls/FamilyCollection/docs`

Comment: one query if i don't specify the id what, from where the document will get the id.And if I dont pass the Id then the error is 401 "The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. "

Comment: @SatheeshKumar So,let me provide the entire rest code for you.Please wait for a while,then you could compare the differences between outs' code.

Comment: @SatheeshKumar Hi,please see my update answer. I provide you with the working code.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answer, for post calls to create hash token

```
Resource method:Post
Resource Id:dbs/{dbs}/colls/{colls}
Resource Type:docs
and the url should be
dbs/{dbs}/colls/{colls}/docs
```